# Online Statistics Python: Variance is not calculating correctly

Tags: python, mean, variance

SOF,
I am new to Python, I have found a lot of info online however it calls for a usage of a list when calculating mean, variance etc. which I cant do. I have no problem calculating the mean for user inputs but the variance is off.

From my understanding variance is the difference between a 'number' and its 'mean' 'squared'. Maybe the problem lies there? I am not sure to be honest, this is my last resort, if you could assist in any way that would be greatly appreciated, I am also open to any advice regarding how I am writing my code.

Thanks!

My code so far:

```
n = input("Enter Number ")
n = int (n)
average = 0

sum = 0

for num in range(0,n+1,1):
        sum = sum + num;

mean = (sum *1.0/ n)

variance = 0

for num in range(n+1):
     sum = (num- mean)**2         

variance = (sum*1.0) 

print("Mean is: ",mean , "Variance is: ",variance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, variance is not just the number-mean squared, it is the sum of all number-mean squared divided by n (or n-1)

The range to calculate variance should start from 1 : `range(1,n+1)`

```
var=0
for num in range(1,n+1):
     var = var +(num- mean)**2
```

Now **variance can be calculated int two ways** : by dividing by `n` or `n-1` thus giving two different answers

```
variance1 = (var*1.0) /n
variance2 = (var*1.0) /(n-1)
```

Eg : for n=10, variance1=8.25 and variance2=9.166666666666666

`n` is used when you're calculating population variance, and `n-1` while calculating sample variance.

Additional details :
Also, while using `range` if your step value is 1, it need not be specified. Use `range(0,n+1)` instead of `range(0,n+1,1)`

Avoid using the same variable `sum` for both mean and variance as it will only cause confusion with the formula.

Comment: Thank you  Sruthi V, I appreciated your input, I made the updates you suggested, ; however, its still displaying incorrect output. For example; for user input ,10, mean should be 5.5 and variance 9.16666666667. I am getting: ('Mean is: ', 5.5, 'Variance is: ', 11.275)

Comment: @Onecam Can you upvote or accept my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

`range(n+1)` gives you a list starting from 0 - n. but what you need it from 1 - n so use `range(1, n+1)`

```
sum = 0
for num in range(1,n+1):
 sum += (num- mean)**2 
variance = sum/n
```

side note: there is a builtin `statistics` library for these.

Comment: Thank you Dawit, I updated my code with your suggestions, however, its still displaying incorrect output. For example; for user input ,10, mean should be 5.5 and variance 9.16666666667. I am getting: ('Mean is: ', 5.5, 'Variance is: ', 11.275)

Answer (score 0):

```
    def mean(n):
        sum = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(n)):
            sum += n[i]
            i += 1
        avg = sum/len(n)
        return avg

    def var(*n):
        y = []
        sum = 0
        i = 0
        for item in n:
            y.append(item)
        for i in range(len(y)):
            sum += (y[i] - mean(y))**2
            i += 1
        variance = sum/len(y)
        return variance
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).